# MDL ready event

Tags: jquery, material-design, jquery-events, material-design-lite, autofocus

[MDL](http://getmdl.io/) is upgrading its components upon page load, so `<input>` with `autofocus` attribute looses its focus. I want to set a focus on this input after MDL finishes rerendering.

I'm trying to listen to some page **ready** event ([codepen](http://codepen.io/mu3/pen/JGqbGz)):

```
$('input#srch').one('componentDidUpdate', function(){console.log('ready')});
```

Not working neither with `$(document)` nor `$(document.body)` nor `$('.mdl-layout')` selectors.
I've googled for some similar events but no luck, am I missing something?
Sure I can use `setTimeout` but I don't think that should be a solution

Answer (score 4):

You can listen to the `mdl-componentupgraded` event on the layout element, `.mdl-ayout`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mdl-layout').on('mdl-componentupgraded', function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).hasClass('mdl-layout')) {
            alert('ready');
        }
    });
});
```

Use `on` instead of `one`. Your page might have multiple elements being upgraded. By using `one` you are going to catch only the first upgrade. With `on` the handler will be called multiple times because of event bubbling. Check `e.target` to react to the specific upgrade of the layout element.

Use a `$(document).ready()` callback. Wait for the DOM to be ready before attaching handlers to its elements. Otherwise the `$('.mdl-layout')` selector might not match and the event handler might not attach.

Comment: Using firefox, the mdl-componentupgraded call is only made after i load the page, then refresh it... Do you have any idea why this could be? Works fine with Chrome

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Check if the material design has finished the rendering */

var mdlLoaded = setInterval(function(){ 
    if(typeof document.querySelector('.mdl-js-layout') !== 'undefined') init()
}, 100)

function init () { 
    clearInterval(mdlLoaded)
    alert('ready')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could listen to the `mdl-componentupgraded` event:

```
$('input#srch').bind('mdl-componentupgraded', function(){console.log('ready')});
```